# Remove site title from all Woocommerce emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to remove site title through the function for all Woocommerce emails. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can override any woocommerce template by copying them to your theme folder. In your particular case the file should be

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php
```

and you should copy it to:

```
wp-content/themes/my-theme-directory/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php
```

Just remove it from there and you should be fine